# Excluding files in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2012 project with thousands of files and folders I wish to exclude from the project as I don't need them to build any longer. Clicking on the folder and choosing Exclude From Project works, but takes forever - at times it appears Visual Studio has stopped running and I have to kill the process.

What is Visual Studio actually doing to exclude a file from a project? Is there a way to simply go into the project file and exclude the files by folder? My project file does not appear to store this information. Where are excluded files defined for the project?

Comment: it does take a ridiculous long time to remove basic files such as images, I’m sat here now doing nothing waiting for mine!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can open the project file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad) and remove the lines with the files that you want to exclude.

You can also do that in Visual Studio but you first need to unload the project (right-click on the project, unload)

Comment: I would have thought the same thing, but the files are not listed there. My project has over 10,000 files and the project file is only 29k.

Comment: yes they are. what is the extension of the file you are looking at?

Comment: Ugh, of course you are right! ...and so was I. I Was looking at an incorrect project file. Sometimes, it just takes someone here to knock some sense into me. Thanks!

Comment: Question, Why does it take so long for VS to exclude them? It took over an hour to exclude 5000 files.

Comment: it rebuilds its internal structures about the project from scratch, dependencies, things like that...

Comment: This comes in handy if you need to exclude a node_module folder you included on accident.

Comment: Or bower_components :P

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder in VS which has project to unload then restore it from recycle bin.
It works for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Realistically, do you think these guys are still waiting for their VS project to unload?